# Passing const unique_ptr reference as parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, smart-pointers

```
 void f1(unique_ptr<A[]>& upA){
    //some work...

    //callee can mess up smart pointer many ways for caller    
    upA.reset();

    //some work...
}

void f2(const unique_ptr<A[]>& upA){
    //some work...

    //compiler stops callee from ruining smart pointer many ways for caller    
    upA.reset();

    //some work...
}

f1(upAArray);
f2(upAArray);
```

In the above code, calling f1 is dangerous because the callee can mess up the smart pointer by resetting it, releasing it, etc.  Calling f2 is safe and everything works great.  If callee tries to do something bad, compiler catches it.  This way, smart pointer is sound when call stack unwinds and we get back to the caller.

IMPORTANT, I'm not asking how best to pass smart pointers (i realize a regular raw pointer void f3(A* pAArray){} would be fine.  I'm asking what is wrong with f2?  The generall advice is to not use const ref to unique_ptr as parameter, while I see why this isn't optimal, I don't see why it is worse than f1().

In short, specifically, what is the rationale against f2()?  Does it do something bad?  It seems safe and sound (though certainly not optimal), I don't see why it is so bad.

Comment: "calling f1 is dangerous" sure they can change it; but the caller knows they can change it; so it's nowhere near as dangerous as you think; and the ownership of the pointer it holds is still very clear

Comment: The "generall advice" is not to pass `unique_ptr` around *by reference* at all. Whether it's `const` or non-`const` isn't the issue. Why does `f1` or `f2` need to take a `unique_ptr`?

Comment: Smart pointers are to express ownership (who is responsible for this pointer).  If you don't need that then you might want to use a different type.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: That's why it's "general advice" rather than "never do this".

Comment: @NicolBolas I guess I misread the comment. Maybe the "at all" part made it sound more absolute to me than was intended.

Comment: Yes, I agree that in the above case, we don't need to pass the smart pointer as a param, but I don't understand why f1() hasn't been vilinized while f(2) has at the C++ conferences.  I agree that both f1 and f2 are non ideal if function is not expected to mod smart pointer.  But why is f2() so much worse?

Comment: If your design does not allow to transfer pointed object ownership to the function pass generic pointers. It will free you from thinking.

Comment: Only pass a unique_ptr by value or by reference if you *want* to transfer ownership.  Likewise with shared_ptr, only pass by value or by reference if you *want* to share ownership.  Otherwise pass as a `Type const&`, or `Type&` or `Type` (copy!) or `Type*` or `Type const*` of the contained type -- with the convention that raw pointers do *not* signify passing ownership.

Comment: *f1() hasn't been vilinized while f2() has* I think this is an assumption that needs to be examined. `f1` makes a lot of sense for a situation where the function is intended to make alterations to the smart-pointer, and therefore it's logical to pass a [non-`const`] reference. `f2` has limited use because if you don't intend to pass ownership, then you probably don't need the details of how the object is owned. But if you're in a situation where you need to know the details of the ownership model, but don't want to make alterations, `f2` is ideal.

Comment: @Xirema When would you need to know the ownership details if you aren't going to do anything with them?

Comment: @NathanOliver The most immediate example that comes to mind is an algorithm operating on `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<T>>`, where functors would be unable to simply take `T const*` as arguments, so you end up using `std::unique_ptr<T> const&` instead.

Comment: @Xirema In that case though your not passing a `unique_ptr` to something but a collection of them.  I'm having a hard time figuring out a reason to pass a `unique_ptr` by `const &` where you need to know your actually getting a `unique_ptr`.  Since you aren't doing anything with it you could just take what the pointer holds since that's all you can work with.  I guess it would make the calling code easier since you just pass the pointer and not `*pointer`.

Comment: I guess the bottom line here is that while there isn't anything "WRONG" with f2, there is no point of using it as alternative is better.  It just doesn't fit with the usage paradime.  Unnecessary coupling as amc176 said.  I thought there was something fundamentally flawed or wrong with it (like odd behavior).  I already understood that it does not fit the paradime and what the proper usage cases were.  Just thought there was more to the case against f2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the drawbacks about passing smart pointers by const reference (or a raw reference) is that the callee depends on implementation details of the caller. Code that doesn't interact with ownership should not be dependant on smart pointers, as their only purpose is modelling ownership.

Comment: what do you mean that the callee depends on the implementation details of the caller?  Could you illustrate with a little code example.  I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @code He means that you know the caller is going to be using a `std::unique_ptr` so you write your function to accept that thus coupling them together.  If the function just needs the array then that is what you should take and you shouldn't care how that array is being stored/managed.

Comment: If you were to change from `unique_ptr` to `shared_ptr` you would have to change all the functions that take a `unique_ptr`, even the ones that don't use the `unique_ptr`. If you had passed a raw pointer from the begining, you wouldn't need to worry about that.