# Passing unique_ptr as reference parameter or const unique_ptr reference

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

I have some pool of objects that I maintain in a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<MyObject>>` and I pass objects from this pool to a function `void process(...)`. I'm not clear on the best way to pass one of these objects to the `process()` function. If I'm understanding the different answers and articles I've read it's best to pass this as a regular reference as follows:
`void process(MyObject& buffer);`

From my understanding this is preferable because:

1. The buffer I'm passing in should be guaranteed to remain in existence throughout the lifetime of the `process()` method by virtue of the fact that it's called by the owner of the unique_ptr, i.e. the calling method
2. the caller can pass stack allocated objects as well so this doesn't impose allocation restrictions on clients of this method
3. If the ptrs can be nullptr then it's advisable to pass a raw pointer to the `process()` method instead

Is this understanding or correct or what is the best guidance? Here are the references I've read:
[Passing const unique_ptr reference as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48811917/passing-const-unique-ptr-reference-as-parameter)

https://www.chromium.org/developers/smart-pointer-guidelines

https://herbsutter.com/2013/06/05/gotw-91-solution-smart-pointer-parameters/

Comment: I don't see a problem with that reasoning.

Comment: That all sounds good. My only question is why you're storing an array of `unique_ptr` rather than `MyObject` itself. That seems to imply the vector can contain null, so I'd go with the pointer approach.

Comment: @CruzJean Do you mean to ask why don't I store raw `MyObject*` pointers instead?

Comment: @MikeSweeney I meant why not `std::vector<MyObject>`. Unless `MyObject` is polymorphic it shouldn't be a problem - just removes a level of indirection.

Comment: @CruzJean It's a non-movable, no-copyable type. It is encapsulating a raw memory buffer. From my understanding that means that wouldn't work but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @MikeSweeney Ah, that makes sense then. Just for completeness I'll say you could use `std::list<MyObject>` since it never moves nodes, but you'd lose out on random access. Of course if you wrote `MyObject` you could simply make it movable if you wanted to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a sensible approach, for the reasons you give.